# having problems making my image upload work on iphone

Tags: iphone, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Here is a fiddle of my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/5S389/

The code works great with my android, but not on my iPhone 4.

After i select a image for upload, the image preview is about 50px height, and 640px width. I have used alert for every calculating operation, and i can see that the numbers are correct. The image showing in the end is however, very wrong.

Anyone have a clue whats going on?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="files">
  <input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader" />
</div>

<div id="cont">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>

<button type="button" id="rotate" >Rotér 90°</button>

<input type="button" id="saveButton" value="LAGRE" onclick="SavePost()" />
```

**JS:**

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var imgWidth = 640;
 var imgHeight = 480;
 var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
 imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
 var size = {
     width: imgWidth,
     height: imgHeight
 };
 var rotation = 0;
 var deg2Rad = Math.PI / 180;
 var img;
 var fileName = "";
 var img;

 function handleImage(e) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function (event) {
         img = new Image;
         img.onload = draw;
         img.src = event.target.result;
         imgWidth = img.width;
         imgHeight = img.height;
         size = {
             width: imgWidth,
             height: imgHeight
         };
     };
     reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
     fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
 }

 function draw() {
     var maxWidth = 640;
     var scale = 1.00;
     if (size.width > maxWidth) {
         scale = maxWidth / size.width;
     }
     canvas.width = size.width * scale;
     canvas.height = size.height * scale;
     // calculate the centerpoint of the canvas
     var cx = canvas.width / 2;
     var cy = canvas.height / 2;

     // draw the rect in the center of the newly sized canvas
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     ctx.save();
     ctx.translate(cx, cy);
     ctx.rotate(rotation * deg2Rad);
     ctx.scale(scale, scale);
     ctx.drawImage(img, -imgWidth / 2, -imgHeight / 2);
     ctx.restore();
 }

 document.getElementById("rotate").addEventListener("click", resizeClicked, false);

 function resizeClicked(e) {
     rotation += 90;
     newSize(imgWidth, imgHeight, rotation);
     draw();
 }

 function newSize(w, h, a) {
     var rads = a * Math.PI / 180;
     var c = Math.abs(Math.cos(rads));
     var s = Math.abs(Math.sin(rads));
     size.width = h * s + w * c;
     size.height = h * c + w * s;
 }

 function SavePost() {
         var canvas = $('canvas')[0];
         var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
         console.log(dataURL);
 }
```

Comment: I seem to be having the same problem on iphone 5. It only happens on SOME phones(regardless of version(4/5)).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with iPhone per-se but that you try to read the width and height of the image perhaps before it is loaded. If the image is in the cache the browser may or may not be able to decode it before you read its size properties. This becomes therefor a bit random and affected by how individual browsers handle image loading.

The error however is in the code due to how image loading is handled (and not with the browser/device) - You can try with this instead:

```
function handleImage(e) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function (event) {
         img = new Image;
         img.onload = draw;
         img.src = event.target.result;
         // image is (maybe) still not loaded here so width = height = 0
     };
     reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
     fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
 }

 function draw() {
     /* Now the size can be read - but this is really
        redundant here as the image is available and can
        be read directly. Inserting it here for compatibility.
     */
     size = {
         width: this.width,
         height: this.height
     };

     var maxWidth = 640;
     var scale = 1.00;
     if (size.width > maxWidth) {
         scale = maxWidth / size.width;
     }
     canvas.width = size.width * scale;
     canvas.height = size.height * scale;

     ...
```

Another possible thing you can check if the size is still wrong is the pixel aspect ratio. You can use this with your calculation:

```
var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

canvas.width = size.width * scale * ratio;
canvas.height = size.height * scale * ratio;

canvas.style.width = (size.width * scale) + 'px';
canvas.style.height = (size.height * scale) + 'px';
```

If the screen is retina then the ratio would be 2. To keep the canvas in the intended space you can add CSS to force the size while the bitmap resolution stays the double.

Hope this helps.